# Why is the standard deviation of the average of averages smaller than the standard deviation of the total?

Tags: machine-learning, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, independence

Say I want to estimate the test error. I can either get $N$ batch $B_i$ then take the average of their average error (so the R.V. is the mean):

$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{n=1} \mu(B)$$

or I can take collect the errors and the take a massive average (so the R.V. is the loss):

$$ \frac{1}{NB} \sum^{NB}_{i=1} L(z_i) $$

I'm fairly certain that they both have the same error, but do they have the same std? From my numerical experiments I don't think they do (which the first one being superior to the second one, especially as B gets larger):

```
Error with average of averages
80%|████████  | 4/5 [01:12<00:18, 18.14s/it]
-> err = 12.598432122111321 +-1.7049395893844483

Error with sum of everything
80%|████████  | 4/5 [01:11<00:17, 17.77s/it]
-> err = 11.505614456176758 +-13.968025155156523
```

what is the difference? Is the covariance some how affecting things, if yes how?

---

I think I understand that I can just make the batch size super big instead of taking lots of averages but now I am just annoyed that I don't understand the difference between these too. I don't think there should be a difference and if there is a difference WHEN does it happen?

Comment: You mentioned covariance. Are the observations (within and across batches)  not independent?

Comment: Is the 1st averaging method computed as:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\mu(B_i) &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{L(z_1^{B_i})+...+L(z_B^{B_i})}{B} \right)\\
 &=  \frac{1}{NB}(L(z_1^{B_1})+...+L(z_{B}^{B_1})+L(z_{1}^{B_2})+...+L(z_{B}^{B_N}))?
\end{align}$$

Comment: @JavierTG yes the second is computed like that. However, the second equality might not be "correct" since the inner sum is the R.V. My entire suspicion is that the two are not ALWAYS equal and I found a case and trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Dayne within a batch the observations are iid. Across batches they might not be. What I am doing is sampling a batch of tasks with a certain number of samples and then take the empirical mean (that is the loss of 1 batch). Then I do that N times. So for 1 batch we have B tasks. Does that make sense?

Comment: So just one more clarification, $z_i$ are observations/tasks which are i.i.d in a batch but not necessarily across batches. That would mean that taking all them together, some are independent and some are not?